# DOJO Charts : Adding intermediate labels in the y- axis for each chart.addSeries()

Tags: graph, charts, dojo, axis-labels

I have added 2 chart.addSeries() and its coming , but i need the labels also should get displayed

```
      chart.addPlot("default", {
    type: "Lines",
    labels: true,
   markers: true  ,
    htmlLabels: true
   });
   // Add X axis
   chart.addAxis("x",{ labels:[{"value":1,"text":"0M"},{"value":1.5,"text":"15M"},{"value":2,"text":"2mmM"},{"value":3,"text":"4M"},{"value":4,"text":"6M"},{"value":5,"text":"8M"},{"value":6,"text":"10M"},{"value":7,"text":"12M"}]});
   // Add Y axis
   chart.addAxis("y", { min: 50, max: 200, vertical: true, fixLower: "major", fixUpper: "major" });
   ADDING SERIES - HERE I WANT THE LABEL ALSO DISPALYED FOR THESE 2 SERIES 
   chart.addSeries("Series A", [110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110], {plot: "other", stroke: {color: "blue", width: 1.5, style:"ShortDash"},outline: null })
   chart.addSeries("Series B", [130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130], {plot: "other",stroke: {color: "blue", width: 1.5, style:"ShortDash"},outline: null })
   --------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Both your series are using some plot named "other" but I don't see it defined on your snippet.
Try to rename the plot you have defined to "other". Also I believe you have to set labelStyle property.